# how to scroll two listview builder simultaneously inside the pageview builder

Tags: flutter

I add the two  listviews builder in pageViewbuilder, the two listviews are separetly scrollable,but I want that the both listviews are scrollable in simultaneously in flutter

Comment: remove the listview physics add on both inside the listview add physics: const NeverScrollablePhysics()

Comment: You can use scrollcontroller for this. add same scrollcontroller to both the lists. This way if you scroll any of the list, both of them will scroll simultaneously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to synchronize the scroll between two `ListView`s by listening to scroll events with [`NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollNotification-class.html). Whenever a scroll event is emitted from one `ListView` set the other `ListView` controller to jump to the same position.

One optimization is to ignore notifications on the other `ListView` if the first or second one is already scrolling. But it also works without this optimization.

This is the result (Check also out the [live demo on DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=d260356debcec143714458406ec4f428)).

[image: Screenshot]

Sources:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: MyHomePage(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

enum ScrollingList {
  none,
  left,
  right,
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State {
  late final ScrollController _controllerLeft;
  late final ScrollController _controllerRight;
  var scrollingList = ScrollingList.none;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controllerLeft = ScrollController();
    _controllerRight = ScrollController();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Row(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
              onNotification: (notification) {
                if (notification is ScrollStartNotification) {
                  if (scrollingList == ScrollingList.none) {
                    scrollingList = ScrollingList.left;
                  }
                } else if (notification is ScrollEndNotification) {
                  if (scrollingList == ScrollingList.left) {
                    scrollingList = ScrollingList.none;
                  }
                }
                if (scrollingList == ScrollingList.left) {
                  _controllerRight.jumpTo(_controllerLeft.offset);
                }
                return true;
              },
              child: ListView.separated(
                controller: _controllerLeft,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Text('Item a$index');
                },
                separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return const Divider();
                },
                itemCount: 100,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          const VerticalDivider(),
          Expanded(
            child: NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
              onNotification: (notification) {
                if (notification is ScrollStartNotification) {
                  if (scrollingList == ScrollingList.none) {
                    scrollingList = ScrollingList.right;
                  }
                } else if (notification is ScrollEndNotification) {
                  if (scrollingList == ScrollingList.right) {
                    scrollingList = ScrollingList.none;
                  }
                }
                if (scrollingList == ScrollingList.right) {
                  _controllerLeft.jumpTo(_controllerRight.offset);
                }
                return true;
              },
              child: ListView.separated(
                controller: _controllerRight,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Text('Item b$index');
                },
                separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return const Divider();
                },
                itemCount: 100,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much,It is very help for me, This part of code worked correctly for my project

Comment: Basiclly, it work. But how to handle when overscroll case. I want to sync 2 listview inlsude overscroll behavior